# Weird indentation in internet explorer (IE)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am using CSS animation elements at the beginning of a page, it renders fine in Google Chrome, but in IE there is a weird indentation happening. Below is the code I am using. I tried various fixes and can't figure it out.

I am not the savviest of programmers as I am NOT a web developer.

Page can be accessed here:

https://secure3.convio.net/little/site/SPageNavigator/Holiday%20Page%20Wrapper/HolidayCampaign2015.html

Below is the code snippet pertaining to the section I am referring to.

```css
.header-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
        background-image: url(https://www.littlecity.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/FusciaChevronPattern-cover.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 font-family: "museo-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 
}
.rw-wrapper{
 width: 80%;
        position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 font-family: "museo-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1;
 
}

.rw-sentence{
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
        display: block;
 position: relative;
        text-transform: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
.rw-sentence span{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600;
        white-space: normal;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) { .rw-sentence span{ font-size: 24px;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) { .rw-sentence span{ font-size: 32px;}}
.rw-words{
 display: inline;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
   
}
.rw-words span{
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: normal;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
 animation: rotateWordsFirst 20s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-2 span{
 animation: rotateWordsSecond 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
 animation-delay: 4s; 
 color: #fff;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
 animation-delay: 8s; 
 color: #fff; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
 animation-delay: 12s; 
 color: #fff;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
 animation-delay: 16s; 
 color: #fff;
}
@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
        0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 100%; }
    10% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
 17% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    23% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    35% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    45% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    55% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    65% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    75% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
.button1{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .75px;
    padding: 15px 21px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.button1 { display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; border: none; }
a.button1:link { color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.blue-bg { background-color: #00bce4;}
.contained-7 { max-width: 735px; }
.centered { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.viewport-two-thirds-height { height: 600px; height: 66.66vh; }
.content-overlay { z-index: 1; position: relative; }
.content-overlay.middle { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 50%; left: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); }
.align-center { text-align: center; }
.padding-3x-2x { padding: 60px 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper viewport-two-thirds-height">
<div class="content-overlay middle">
<h2 class="rw-sentence">
  <img class="padding-2x" src="https://www.littlecity.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/TagYoureIt_type.png" alt="Tag You're It!" /><br />
  <span>When you give, you</span><br />
<div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
  <span>provide opportunities for people to work.</span>
  <span>allow students to learn.</span>
  <span>help preserve families and strengthen relationships.</span>
  <span>improve the overall quality of life of the individuals we serve.</span>
  <span>spread happiness and joy to each of our children and adults.</span>
                </div>
</h2>
<div class="contained-7 centered align-center padding-3x-2x">
<a class="button1 blue-bg" title="Give Now" href="https://little.convio.net">Give Now</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, try this one? I have accessed it via mobile as well so it should work https://secure3.convio.net/little/site/SPageNavigator/Holiday%20Page%20Wrapper/HolidayCampaign2015.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I think that IE is the correct way. Anyway, remove the `display: inline;` from the parent `div` and add `left: 0;` to the `span`:

```css
.header-wrapper{
 width: 100%;
        background-image: url(https://www.littlecity.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/FusciaChevronPattern-cover.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 font-family: "museo-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 
}
.rw-wrapper{
 width: 80%;
        position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 font-family: "museo-sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1;
 
}

.rw-sentence{
 margin: 0;
 text-align: center;
        display: block;
 position: relative;
        text-transform: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
}
.rw-sentence span{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 600;
        white-space: normal;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) { .rw-sentence span{ font-size: 24px;}}
@media (min-width: 768px) { .rw-sentence span{ font-size: 32px;}}
.rw-words{
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
}
.rw-words span{
  left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 color: #fff;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: normal;
}
.rw-words-1 span{
 animation: rotateWordsFirst 20s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words-2 span{
 animation: rotateWordsSecond 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
 animation-delay: 4s; 
 color: #fff;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
 animation-delay: 8s; 
 color: #fff; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
 animation-delay: 12s; 
 color: #fff;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
 animation-delay: 16s; 
 color: #fff;
}
@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
        0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 100%; }
    10% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
 17% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    23% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    35% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    45% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    55% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    65% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    75% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    100% { opacity: 0;}
}
.button1{
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: .75px;
    padding: 15px 21px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a.button1 { display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; vertical-align: top; border: none; }
a.button1:link { color: #fff; text-decoration: none;}
.blue-bg { background-color: #00bce4;}
.contained-7 { max-width: 735px; }
.centered { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.viewport-two-thirds-height { height: 600px; height: 66.66vh; }
.content-overlay { z-index: 1; position: relative; }
.content-overlay.middle { position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 50%; left: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); }
.align-center { text-align: center; }
.padding-3x-2x { padding: 60px 40px; }
```

```html
<div class="header-wrapper viewport-two-thirds-height">
<div class="content-overlay middle">
<h2 class="rw-sentence">
  <img class="padding-2x" src="https://www.littlecity.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/TagYoureIt_type.png" alt="Tag You're It!" /><br />
  <span>When you give, you</span><br />
<div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
  <span>provide opportunities for people to work.</span>
  <span>allow students to learn.</span>
  <span>help preserve families and strengthen relationships.</span>
  <span>improve the overall quality of life of the individuals we serve.</span>
  <span>spread happiness and joy to each of our children and adults.</span>
                </div>
</h2>
<div class="contained-7 centered align-center padding-3x-2x">
<a class="button1 blue-bg" title="Give Now" href="https://little.convio.net">Give Now</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solved the problem beautifully! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: 
 1. You have `a` element with a wrong typed class name `button2 greenbg` instead of `button2 green-bg`;
2. `.text1, a.text1:link{color:white}` instead of `.text1, a.text1:link{ color:black}`(i added black only to suggest you that you have a white text on a white background)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out on the button. Regarding the white text, not sure what happened but the container for that is supposed to be solid green, hence the white text. But I am looking into it now.